# Dynamic div when adding element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting an image name via an ajax and php call getting information from an sql table. The problem is all the images are different sizes and i want them to all sit at the bottom of a div. All the solutions to this problem only work if the image is defined when creating the div.

It gets the image name and prints it to screen fine, however, it is at the top of the div, i have also tried having the div set to auto but it just stays as a 0px by 0px div even after the image is added.

CSS

```
.enemy{
        height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0
    }
.enemydiv{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 206;
    left: 800px;
    margin-top: 252px;
        }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var enemy = document.createElement("div");
    enemy.className = "enemy";
    enemy.id = "enemy"; 
    document.getElementById("enemydiv").appendChild(enemy); 
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'enemy.php',
    data: {act:act, name:name, attack:attack},
    success: function(value){
        var data = value.split(",");
        var name = data[0];
        var attack = data[1];
        var level = data[2];
        document.getElementById("enemy").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + name + ")";
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently updating image style by adding backgroundImage and this will not change your div size. Use img tag instead

Comment: Might be a stupid question but how do you do that in javascript?

Comment: no it's not a stupid question. You can do that by adding <img id="myImage" 
src=""> in your html and then in your success callback  document.getElementById("myImage").src = name;

Comment: Its now saying that the image is not found

Comment: document.getElementById("myimage").src = name; , the css hasnt changed and the html looks like this <div class = "enemydiv" id = "enemydiv"><img id ="myimage" src=""></div>

Comment: when you say that you're getting image is not found, you're talking about an http error? if its the case you've something wrong in your image url.

Comment: that's why i'm a bit confused because in the console the error message has the correct image name with .png which is what it is but it's apparently not found on the server. This is after it worked fine before getting the image.

Comment: So this is a different problem from your initial question

Comment: Yeah im going to assume your fix works though, thanks for your help